# Creating Process Map Diagrams using different packages in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, business-process-management, ggplotly

the given script simply creates a process map diagram showing the flow of events in R. This field of study is called event log mining or process mining. I wish to know any other packages or functionality in R using which I can create similar maps and also make them interactive like ggplotly. Please help me with some links if possible. Thanks and please help.

```
library(bupaR)
library(edeaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(processmapR)
library(processmonitR)
library(xesreadR)
library(petrinetR)
patients %>% process_map()
```

[image: Basic Process Map snapshot]

Comment: did you find a solution for plotly like interactive maps? Just a simple flow diagram where you click and see some information would be awesome.